# With the Adobe Flex SDK 3.0 (most recent), can you create 'charts'?

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, mxml

Just googling on the web, it looks like you can't.  It seems you need the Flex builder.  I was trying to avoid the fully GUI tool.  Is there a way to bypass this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest Flex SDK is 3.2 and no, they don't include the charting components. You need a license for Flex Builder 3 Professional which includes the charting components.

If you already have this and need to move to a new version of the SDK for your project then you need to manually copy the charting component swcs into the new SDK folder.  Just did a search for the instructions to do this:

> If your application uses Flex Builder
> Professional features such as data
> visualization components or automated
> testing, you will need to copy those
> elements from the latest milestone SDK
> that came with Flex Builder into your
> newly downloaded SDK. The relevant
> files that you need to copy are:
>
> {sdkdir}/frameworks/libs/automation*.swc
>
> {sdkdir}/frameworks/libs/datavisualization.swc
>
> {sdkdir}/frameworks/locale/en_US/automation*.swc
>
> {sdkdir}/frameworks/locale/en_US/datavisualization_rb.swc
>
> {sdkdir}/frameworks/locale/ja_JP/automation*.swc
>
> {sdkdir}/frameworks/locale/ja_JP/datavisualization_rb.swc
>
> {sdkdir}/frameworks/rsls/datavisualization_3.0.0.477.* (or updated build numbers for later builds)
>
> {sdkdir}/fbpro (if you care
> about source)

Answer (score 0):

The charting components are part of Flex Builder Professional. If you have the charting swc's, you can use the charts without Flex Builder though. You'll need to have a valid license in order to get rid of the watermark.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Christophe, you can also roll your own charting component. It's not that hard.

Comment: For very, very simple charts, maybe. Creating a full charting engine that offers the same features as Flex's charts is not trivial.